# ReactJS Axios Nginx CORS issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, nginx, axios, cors

I am using `React 15.6.1, Axios, NGINX`. I am getting CORS issue on Login. Below is the Login axios `POST` call

```
const additionalHeaders = {
  code: action.payload,
  page: 'login'
};
const loginData = yield call(() =>
  axios(authorization, 'Basic', additionalHeaders).post(
    URL + ACCESS_TOKEN_URL,
    params
  )
);
```

Below is the error console

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at '..../oauth/token' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' 
has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field sourcepage is not allowed by 
Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.
utils.js:258 uncaught at tryLogin 
 at takeLatestHelper 
 at login 
 TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined
    at login$ (webpack-internal:///./app/containers/Login/saga.js:137:43)
    at tryCatch (webpack:///./node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js?:65:40)
    at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (webpack:///./node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js?:303:22)
    at Generator.prototype.<computed> [as throw] (webpack:///./node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js?:117:21)
    at next (webpack:///./node_modules/redux-saga/es/internal/proc.js?:289:32)
    at currCb (webpack:///./node_modules/redux-saga/es/internal/proc.js?:387:7)
    at eval (webpack:///./node_modules/redux-saga/es/internal/proc.js?:443:14)
..
..
xhr.js:160 POST .../aas/oauth/token net::ERR_FAILED
```

Below is what i have tried, which is not working.

I have NGINX configuration. I have added the `add_header` params for `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`

```
 # Always serve index.html for any request
location / {
  add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' "*";
  add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
  add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS';
  add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Accept,Authorization,Cache-Control,Content-Type,DNT,If-Modified-Since,Keep-Alive,Origin,User-Agent,X-Requested-With';
  # Set path
  root /var/www/;
  try_files $uri /index.html;

}
```

And we have 3 nodejs middleWare files `frontendMiddleWare.js`, `devMiddleware.js`, `prodMiddleWare.js` i have added the below access in `fontendMiddleware`

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,POST,PUT");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization");
  next();
});
```

I couldn't find more solns on the client end and still not able to solve the issue.

EDIT : This issue is showing up for the 2nd time. First time i am able to see the token with 200 response and working.. When application is loaded when i try to hit login, it will try to get the token again. at this point CORS issue is showing up.

Comment: cors setup must be from backend & from backend give access to url& port like locahost:3000 or something .

Comment: @Matarishvan did you find my answer usefull ?

Comment: @VinodSai the changes weren't working in my case. Because i am unaware of the CORS setup in backend.

Comment: @Matarishvan you dont need to worry about cors if you try my answer. Im using it in my project. Its working fine

Comment: @VinodSai I have already used it.. I have added `"proxy": "http://localhost:8000",` in my package.json. But it doesnt work

Comment: Did you restart the react server

Comment: @VinodSai yes i did

Comment: Btw your api should call react port.. it will redirect to the 8000 port

Answer (score 0):

We can create a proxy in package.json file, which calls the backend server if the route is not available in the frontend. We can add a key in package.json named proxy and give the backend api as value

```
proxy: http://localhost:PORT_NUMBER_OF_BACKEND
```

> Remember to stop the react server and start it again for this to work

source https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/

In this case we wont get cors error, and in production we can generate build and place it in the public folder of website backend, so there wont be any issue of cors in production.

Answer (score 0):

You can add cors package on your application, first you should install cors package `npm install cors --save` after that do something like this:

```
const cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors());
```

Remove all other extra headers you put on Nginx conf and your middleware file.

Hopefully, It will work

Comment: Have tried. Doesnt work. Not sure if the cors setup has to be made from backend

Answer (score -1):

You can use [fruitcake/laravel-cors](https://github.com/fruitcake/laravel-cors) package to make exception and fix the api route.